# my echo "<tr> </tr"; error when i use bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrapper, tr

```
echo "<tr class ='a'>
<td>".$data->id."</td>
<td>".$data->nis."</td>
<td>".$data->nama."</td>
<td>".$data->jenis_kelamin."</td>
<td>".$data->telp."</td>
<td>".$data->alamat."</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="'.base_url("siswa/ubah/".$data->id).'">Ubah</a></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="'.base_url("siswa/hapus/".$data->id).'">Hapus</a></td>
</tr>";
```

its error when i use bootstrap in my coding, how to keep this from error?

Comment: Just check you are missing form tag

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<?php
    echo "<tr class ='a'>
    <td>".$data->id."</td>
    <td>".$data->nis."</td>
    <td>".$data->nama."</td>
    <td>".$data->jenis_kelamin."</td>
    <td>".$data->telp."</td>
    <td>".$data->alamat."</td>
    <td><a class=\"btn btn-warning\" href=".base_url("siswa/ubah/".$data->id).">Ubah</a></td>
    <td><a class=\"btn btn-warning\" href=".base_url("siswa/hapus/".$data->id).">Hapus</a></td>    
    </tr>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Hope it will help you

`<td><?php echo $data->id; ?></td>`

`<td><?php echo $data->ins; ?></td>`

`<td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>`

`<td><?php echo $data->jenis_kelamin; ?></td>`

`<td><?php echo $data->telp; ?></td>`

`<td><?php echo $data->alamat; ?></td>`

`<td><a class=\"btn btn-warning\" href="<php echo base_url("siswa/ubah/".$data->id)?>">Ubah</a></td>`

```
<td><a class=\"btn btn-warning\" href="<?php echo base_url("siswa/hapus/".$data->id)?>">Hapus</a></td>
```